# Setting value of textarea via variable does not work, via document.getElementID does

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to expand my understanding of JavaScript with this question.

I have a "comments" variable, which I have set using the following call:

```
comments = document.getElementById('txtComments_' + id).value;
```

Note that comments is pointing to a textarea. I have checked the value of comments, and I am sure that I have selected the correct ID. I was using this information to implement a placeholder, so I wanted to set the value of comments to be an empty string. I tried the following, and found that I could not set the value of the textarea.

```
comments = ''; //This does not work
```

Thinking that it might have something to do with the value call, I tried:

```
comments = document.getElementById('txtComments_' + id);
comments.value = '';
```

And that still didn't work. I searched around SO, and I eventually found that the following call works flawlessly:

```
document.getElementById('txtComments_' + id).value = '';
```

**So my question is this**: what is the difference between setting the textarea to a variable versus the document.getElementByID? It seems to me like some functionality was lost when I set it to a variable, but looking around I can't seem to find why that is. Just to be clear, I am not using jQuery.

Comment: The first one doesn't work because assigning a value to a variable **never** changes any other variable or property. The second example should work though.

Comment: Reference vs. primitive. The element is an object, the value is a primitive.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: It actually doesn't have anything to do  with ref vs primitive. More like assigning to property vs assigning to a variable. Or *pass-by-reference* vs *pass-by-value* (where reference doesn't mean "object reference").

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that never crossed my mind. Though I would have thought that assigning it as document.getElementById('txtComments_' + id) and then calling value would have worked...Anyway, if either of you want to put your responses in to an answer, I'd be happy to accept them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MP8zM/5/  sorry but it worked for mee...

Comment: As I said, the second example should work fine. If it doesn't for you, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @ControlAltDeplete I've change my answer. i think that var absence could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared your variable with `var` ? If not, the problem could be a conflict with a global var or an element with id = 'comments'

```
    var comments = document.getElementById('elementID');
    comments.value = '';
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have taken over this code from a colleague, and the lack of a var didn't even catch my eye. Adding the "var" made it work. Thank you!